# HTML CSS div floating left goes under , below div floating right?

Tags: css, html, css-float, floating

I'm hoping someone can help me: I have a left column container #left-column, with a float:left; and some elements (slideshow, images, text) floating on the right. Everything is placed in the main container which has a width value of 990px; The left column is 240px, while all the elements on the right have widths which are enough to fit on the right side (720px). Here is a graphic of what is happening:

What can I do to solve this ? My guess is that there is something to do with the slideshow div...

[image: Left column floats to left; all the other elements (slideshow, images, text) are floating to the right. The left column goes under the slideshow for some reason...]

```css
#main-container {
    width:990px;
    margin:8px auto;
}
#left-column {
    width:240px;
    float:left;
}
#slideshow {
    float:right;
    width:720px;
    height:300px;
}
a.image {
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
.text {
    float:right;
    width:720px;
}
```

What should I do ? MANY thanks...!!

EDIT - When I put a position:asbolute to the left-column container, it goes straight up to the top, which looks fine , but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Need more info, put it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Could you provide with the HTML you use?

Comment: Pretty much any answer is a guess unless we can see html

Comment: @all Sorry guys the html would be too long to copy and past because it's in a CMS. I replied to my question because I found the answer. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who gave me some tips and hints to solve my problem. After messing around abit in the code I found that placing the left column BEFORE the slideshow was the solution. Something I missed: the slideshow container was after the left column... Basically the order of things on the page was not right. As this html code is outputed with some PHP I didn't see it at first, also sorry but could hardly post the whole html code, thanks to everybody though I really appreciated your replies trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to understand specifically for your context without the HTML, but here is a global idea : you generally don't need to put `float: left;` for left column, and `float: right;` for right column, even if it seems logical for you.

An easier and more reliable way would be to put **all** your elements that will be next to each other on `float: left;` (so the right column would be floating left, just near the left column)

With your image, I would do something like that :

```
<div id="leftColumn">
</div>
<div id="rightColumn">
    <div id="slideshow"></div>
    <div id="imgWrapper">
        <div class="imgDiv"></div>
        <div class="imgDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>


#leftColumn {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#rightColumn {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imgDiv {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#imgWrapper { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replyy, I found out the solution and answered my question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Check the margin on both the #left-column and the #slideshow.  The width of an element only takes into account border and padding.  Your total width is 990px.  #left-column is 240px and #slideshow is 720px.  240+720 is 960px.  So if you have more than 30px of margin, one of the elements has to move down.

Comment: Thanks for your replyy, I found out the solution and answered my question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Try to divide the main wrapper into 2 cols like this. (i add a footer incase u need it later)

[Codepen](http://cdpn.io/sBdwq)

then just put the other div's inside

```
<div id="main-container">
 <div id="left-column">left-column</div> 

 <div id="right-column">right-column</div> 


 <div id="footer">footer</div> 


</div>
```

and for the css

```
#main-container {
    width:990px;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
#left-column {
    width:240px;
    float:left;
  height:300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#right-column {
    width:720px;
    height:300px;
      float:left;
    background-color: green;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    width:990px;
    height:50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replyy, I found out the solution and answered my question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Either set

```
vertical-align:top; //to left column `#left-column`
```

Or

Try reducing `#slideshow` width

make sure you are making clear both the floating `divs`

Comment: Thanks for your replyy, I found out the solution and answered my question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

use a minus margin-top for #left-column with the value of your #slidshow height

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found out the solution and answered my question. Thanks though!